# Expand background-image on mobile device to fit body

Tags: html, css

I have 5 divs which are responsible for website's background. When user hovers pointer on one of action divs, background changes. On desktop background image displays perfectly, but in mobile browser I have something like on screenshot - image repeats
[image]

I have this css

```
.page_background
{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
#bg_def
{
    background: url("/images/bg.jpg") fixed top !important;
}
#bg_kvadro
{
    background: url("/images/bg_kvadr.jpg") fixed top !important;
    display: none;
}

#bg_hotel
{
    background: url("/images/bg_hotel.jpg") fixed top !important;
    display: none;
}

#bg_palatka
{
    background: url("/images/bg_base.jpg") fixed top !important;
    display: none;
}

#bg_eat
{
    background: url("/images/bg_rest.jpg") fixed top !important;
    display: none;
}
```

Part of html code

```
<body>

<div class="page_background" id="bg_def"></div>
<div class="page_background" id="bg_hotel"></div>   
<div class="page_background" id="bg_eat"></div> 
<div class="page_background" id="bg_palatka"></div> 
<div class="page_background" id="bg_kvadro"></div>
```

My question is: how to expand image to fit body?

Comment: If you can provide a link - we can test it on mobile and give you an answer

Comment: I can't see the issue in mobile... looks OK.
How to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @YonatanAyalon I tried in Chrome for iOS, iOS v 8.4. What is your browser and OS?

Answer (score 0):

Define the image as child, not as background.

Comment: @rulisp yes, with the appropriate CSS